# Xcode 6, iOS 8 Core Location not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, core-location

I am updating an iOS 7 app that uses Core Data to iOS 8, and encountered the Core Location problem that's well-known. Last night I added `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to plist and sent method to locationManager. Core Location worked. Saved, committed, made no other changes and closed Xcode.

For some reason now, Core Location doesn't work again. Anyone else have this problem? What's the fix?

Comment: Are you checking in simulator? If then check you have selected a location for simulate location in Xcode

Comment: @Anil yep, that's taken care of, still nothing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031155/core-location-with-xcode-6-simulator - that's my solution, have only tested in simulator not on actual device