# Core Location with Xcode 6 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode6, core-location

Core Location is not calling `didUpdateLocations`. I have 2 classes involved LocationManager and a View Controller. Plist is set for `requestAlwaysAuthorization`. Location is simulated in debug. Can anyone help me spot the error?

LocationManager.h

```
@interface LPLocationManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

+(LPLocationManager*)sharedManager;

@property (strong, atomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *location;
@end
```

LocationManager.m

```
+(LPLocationManager*)sharedManager{
    static LPLocationManager *sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedManager = [[LPLocationManager alloc]init];
    });

    return sharedManager;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;

    }

    return self;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{


    self.location = [locations lastObject];

    [self setCurrentLocation:self.location];

    NSLog(@"self.location in didupdatelocation %@", self.location);

    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```

ViewController.m (where startUpdating is called)

```
- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {


    LPLocationManager *locationObject = [LPLocationManager sharedManager];
    NSLog(@"location object %@", locationObject);
    [locationObject.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    NSLog(@"locationManager %@", locationObject.locationManager);
    [locationObject.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(getLocation:) name:@"locationNotification" object:nil];

    [refreshControl endRefreshing];

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844430/xcode-6-gm-cllocationmanager/25844674#25844674

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out.

In simulator, go to Settings -> General and scroll to Reset. Click Reset Location & Privacy.

Close simulator and rerun app. Back in Settings, go to Privacy -> Location and select Always for the app.

Comment: It shows the prompt which asks for authorization but

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

gets called immedietly and the error i get is

Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

Comment: And you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working

Comment: yes, i added
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in info.plist and also called
if ([ClLM respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [ClLM requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

Comment: i am checking in simulator

Comment: it has also shown the prompted the message that i used with NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in info.plist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032976/didfailwitherror-error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-0-the-operation-couldn-t-be check out this answer - a lot of different answers. this happened to me but I can't remember what the fix was

Comment: i forgot to restart simulator earlier, sorry

Comment: The other way to fix it is to (1)Start the app. (2)Let simulator with app load. (3)Set location (4)Un-set location (5)Reset location

Answer (score 1):

add these key-values in your info.plist file

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

after this define this macro

```
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
```

and put this code in viewWillAppear

```
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: I did the above, but it still didn't work. It's an issue with simulator. See answer below.